# How to plot dichotomous presence/absence data to complement timeseries data

Tags: r, ggplot2, binary, time-series, data-visualization

I have a daily logger data for several variables. For this example I use 3 variables: precipitation, distance and I dichotomous variable (1/0) which is 1 if the precipitation is in the form of rain and 0 if there is no precipitation or the precipitation is in the form of snow. Here is an example of how the data looks like:

```
date <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2010-11-2','2010-11-3','2010-11-4','2010-11-5','2010-11-6','2010-11-7','2010-11-8','2010-11-9','2010-11-10'))
distance <- c(5,4,4,7,9,7,NA,5,6,4)
precipitation <- c(11,15,NA,0,3,0,2,2,9,10)
dicht <- c(1,1,NA,0,1,0,1,0,0,1)

df <- data.frame(date, distance, precipitation, dicht)
```

```
date distance precipitation dicht
1  2010-11-01        5            11     1
2  2010-11-02        4            15     1
3  2010-11-03        4            NA    NA
4  2010-11-04        7             0     0
5  2010-11-05        9             3     1
6  2010-11-06        7             0     0
7  2010-11-07       NA             2     1
8  2010-11-08        5             2     0
9  2010-11-09        6             9     0
10 2010-11-10        4            10     1
```

Distance (snow gliding distance) in this case is a dependent variable. It depends on precipitation (and bunch of other factors which are irrelevant for the question). I hypothesize that precipitation in the form of rain will lead to a increased gliding. The "precipitation" variable itself does not differentiate between rain and snow. That is why I have the dichotomous variable which I created based on several conditions and several other variables that are not included here. My goal is to somehow visualize this whole thing. This is the plot that I have so far (for the example data that present you here):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(patchwork)
library(dplyr)

#### Setting up language settings and start time and endtime. 

Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "english")

startTime <- as.Date("2010-11-01")
endTime <- as.Date("2010-11-10")
start_end <- c(startTime,endTime)

#### Plotting

scale <- max(df$distance, na.rm = T) / max(df$precipitation, na.rm = T)

ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = date, y = distance, color = "Average daily gliding distance"),na.rm= TRUE, size = 1)+
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = date, y = precipitation*scale ,color = "Daily precipitation amount"),na.rm = TRUE, size = 1) +
  ggtitle("Daily precipitation & Average Gliding Distance") +
  labs(color = "")+
  xlab("2010")+
  ylab("Accumulated Distance [mm]")+
  scale_x_date(limits=start_end,breaks=date_breaks("1 day"),labels=date_format("%d %b"))+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./scale,name = "Daily precipitation amount"),limits = c(0, 15))+
  scale_color_manual("", guide = "legend",
                     values = c("Average daily gliding distance"= "darkorange2",
                                "Daily precipitation amount" = "black"))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
        #legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 50, size = 10 , vjust = 0.5),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, vjust = 0.5), 
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "gray100"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "gray100"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "lightblue"),
        plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "cm"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 22))
```

[image]

On the x-axis I have date. As you can see I have a dual Y-axis for the two variables which I scaled for better visualization. I included NA's in the data for better representation of the real data that I have. Now the problem that I have is I would like to fit in the dichotomous data somehow. I need to somehow indicate on the graph when precipitation is in the form of rain [df$dicht == 1] or in the form of snow [df$dicht == 0] . Is there a way I can somehow mark the precipitation line for each datapoint (timepoint) based on the dichotomous values? I know it might get too crowded but in the worst case scenario I need to at least indicate whenever [df$dicht == 1]. Alternatively, if you think that other way of indicating whenever precipitation is in the form of rain is more suitable than putting a symbol on the precipitation line, I am very glad to check it out. In general, if you have fundamentally different statistical/visualization approach feel free to suggest it. Let me know if you would need more explanation/data/examples etc. Thanks in advance.

Zorin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least two options in this case:

1. Set different line types depending on the value of the `dicht` variable
2. Use [`facet_wrap()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_wrap.html) to plot one graph for each value of `dicht`

I have removed the NAs to improve the visualization.

The approach using different line types is the following:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = df[!is.na(df$dicht),], aes(x = date, y = distance, color = "Average daily gliding distance", linetype=as.factor(dicht)),na.rm= TRUE, size = 1)+
  geom_line(data = df[!is.na(df$dicht),], aes(x = date, y = precipitation*scale ,color = "Daily precipitation amount", linetype=as.factor(dicht)),na.rm = TRUE, size = 1) +
  ggtitle("Daily precipitation & Average Gliding Distance") +
  labs(color = "")+
  xlab("2010")+
  ylab("Accumulated Distance [mm]")+
  scale_x_date(limits=start_end,breaks=date_breaks("1 day"),labels=date_format("%d %b"))+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./scale,name = "Daily precipitation amount"),limits = c(0, 15))+
  scale_color_manual("", guide = "legend",
                     values = c("Average daily gliding distance"= "darkorange2",
                                "Daily precipitation amount" = "black"))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
        #legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 50, size = 10 , vjust = 0.5),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, vjust = 0.5), 
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "gray100"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "gray100"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "lightblue"),
        plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "cm"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 22)) +
  scale_linetype_manual("Preciptation type",values=c(1, 2), labels=c("No precipitation", "Rain"))
```

[image: Plot using different line types]

The approach with `facet_wrap()` is the following:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = df[!is.na(df$dicht),], aes(x = date, y = distance, color = "Average daily gliding distance"),na.rm= TRUE, size = 1)+
  geom_line(data = df[!is.na(df$dicht),], aes(x = date, y = precipitation*scale ,color = "Daily precipitation amount"),na.rm = TRUE, size = 1) +
  ggtitle("Daily precipitation & Average Gliding Distance") +
  labs(color = "")+
  xlab("2010")+
  ylab("Accumulated Distance [mm]")+
  scale_x_date(limits=start_end,breaks=date_breaks("1 day"),labels=date_format("%d %b"))+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./scale,name = "Daily precipitation amount"),limits = c(0, 15))+
  scale_color_manual("", guide = "legend",
                     values = c("Average daily gliding distance"= "darkorange2",
                                "Daily precipitation amount" = "black"))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
        #legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 50, size = 10 , vjust = 0.5),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, vjust = 0.5), 
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "gray100"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "gray100"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "lightblue"),
        plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "cm"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 22)) +
  facet_wrap(~dicht, labeller = as_labeller(c("0"="No precipitation", "1"="Rain")))
```

[image: Plot with facet_wrap()]

The first approach is more appropriate, since there is only one value per day and it's either raining or not raining. However, both these approaches visually "interpolate" the missing values, stretching the line from the last non-null value to the next one, even when there is no data available.
Therefore, I would suggest you use [`geom_point()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_point.html) instead:

```
ggplot()+
geom_point(data = df[!is.na(df$dicht),], aes(x = date, y = distance, color = "Average daily gliding distance", shape=as.factor(dicht)),na.rm= TRUE, size = 5)+
geom_point(data = df[!is.na(df$dicht),], aes(x = date, y = precipitation*scale ,color = "Daily precipitation amount", shape=as.factor(dicht)),na.rm = TRUE, size = 5) +
ggtitle("Daily precipitation & Average Gliding Distance") +
labs(color = "")+
xlab("2010")+
ylab("Accumulated Distance [mm]")+
scale_x_date(limits=start_end,breaks=date_breaks("1 day"),labels=date_format("%d %b"))+
scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./scale,name = "Daily precipitation amount"),limits = c(0, 15))+
scale_color_manual("", guide = "legend",
                   values = c("Average daily gliding distance"= "darkorange2",
                              "Daily precipitation amount" = "black"))+
theme(legend.position="bottom",
      #legend.title = element_blank(),
      axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 50, size = 10 , vjust = 0.5),
      axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, vjust = 0.5), 
      panel.background = element_rect(fill = "gray100"),
      plot.background = element_rect(fill = "gray100"),
      panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "lightblue"),
      plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "cm"),
      plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 22)) +
scale_shape_manual("Preciptation type",values=c(1, 18), labels=c("No precipitation", "Rain"))
```

[image: Plot with geom_point()]

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the solutions. I'm not sure about the computations behind the first and second solution but it is not the result I am looking for. However, solution 3 is more or less what I was trying to achieve. I also upgraded it with lines in between the points.  I will add the code and the graph in a new comment just in case it might be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the 3rd solution of @Paulo Schau Guerra, I added lines in between the points:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = date, y = distance, color = "Average daily gliding distance"),na.rm= TRUE, size = 1)+
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = date, y = precipitation*scale ,color = "Daily precipitation amount"),na.rm = TRUE, size = 1) +
  geom_point(data = df[!is.na(df$dicht),], aes(x = date, y = distance, color = "Average daily gliding distance", shape=as.factor(dicht)),na.rm= TRUE, size = 5)+
  geom_point(data = df[!is.na(df$dicht),], aes(x = date, y = precipitation*scale ,color = "Daily precipitation amount", shape=as.factor(dicht)),na.rm = TRUE, size = 5) +
  ggtitle("Daily precipitation & Average Gliding Distance") +
  labs(color = "")+
  xlab("2010")+
  ylab("Accumulated Distance [mm]")+
  scale_x_date(limits=start_end,breaks=date_breaks("1 day"),labels=date_format("%d %b"))+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./scale,name = "Daily precipitation amount"),limits = c(0, 15))+
  scale_color_manual("", guide = "legend",
                     values = c("Average daily gliding distance"= "darkorange2",
                                "Daily precipitation amount" = "black"))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
        #legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 50, size = 10 , vjust = 0.5),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, vjust = 0.5), 
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "gray100"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "gray100"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "lightblue"),
        plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "cm"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 22))+
  scale_shape_manual("Preciptation type",values=c(1, 18), labels=c("No precipitation", "Rain"))
```

[image]